# How to bind a {{}} to the return value of a angular js $scope method?

Tags: angularjs, handlebars.js, meanjs

I have method :

```
$scope.resortLocation=function(resort_id){
        $scope.resorts.forEach(function(sel_resort){

            if(sel_resort.resort_id===resort_id){
                console.log(sel_resort.name );
                return sel_resort.name;

            }
        });
      }
```

And the html is :

```
 <tr ng-repeat="x in bookings | filter:{membership_id:user.membership_id} | filter:upcomingFilter">
                            <td><a ng-href="#!/bookings/{{x._id}}">{{x.booking_id}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                            </td>
 /*I want the result here*/ <td>{{resortLocation(x.resort_id)}}</td>
                            <td>{{x.checkin_time | date : "mediumDate"}}</td>
                            <td>{{x.checkout_time | date : "mediumDate"}}</td>
                            <td>{{x.points}}</td>
                            <td>{{x.cancelled}}</td>
                        </tr>
```

While the "resortLocation" function is getting called successfully the return value is not appear on the screen at the location of `{{resortLocation(x.resort_id)}}`. What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: have you got the ouput in console ?I mean your console statement is working ?

Comment: Your method, `resortLocation`, doesn't return anything. The only `return` in your code is in the inner function that you're passing to `forEach`.

Comment: @JAAulde bingo that's why i was asking that is his console statement working :)

Comment: Yes the console.log is working fine. Only return is not returning to the html

Comment: @jackOfAll Did my answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

As JAAulde mentioned resortLocation doesn't return a value only the foreach does.

In addition, my guess is that when you find the required resort you don't want to keep on iterating the entire resorts array.
In that case you can use [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) in a nice way: stop "every" iteration process by returning false.

So you can use this code (If resort wasn't found, the name returned will be an empty string):

```
$scope.resortLocation=function(resort_id){
        var resortName = "";
        $scope.resorts.every(function(sel_resort){
            if(sel_resort.resort_id===resort_id){
                console.log(sel_resort.name );
                resortName = sel_resort.name;
                return false; //Stopping the "every" loop
            }
            else{
            return true;
            }
            });
        return resortName; //returning resort name if exists, if not empty string
        }
```

EDIT:
Corrected the code and added a working [Plunker with the same logic](http://plnkr.co/edit/KBgoquEDEB0Crq9CfIOf?p=preview).

Comment: This solution is all not rendering the value on the screen.

Comment: Yeah with minor changes. This is the code that worked in my program :

 $scope.resortLocation=function(resort_id){
          var resortName = "";
        $scope.resorts.forEach(function(sel_resort){            
            if(sel_resort.resort_id===resort_id){               
                resortName = sel_resort.name;                
                return false;
            }            
        });
            return resortName;
      };

Comment: @jackOfAll good! If so you can mark that my answer solved your issue. Good day!

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the value in order to expose this to scope and return true to avoid extra loop iterations. I Addition, I'm using ngBind to avoid momentarily displayed by the browser in its raw state before Angular compiles it.

```
$scope.resortLocation = function(resort_id){
  var resortName = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.resorts.length; i++){
    if($scope.resorts[i].resort_id===resort_id){
        console.log($scope.resorts[i].name);
        resortName = $scope.resorts[i].name;
        break;
    }
  };
  return resortName;
}
```

[Here your example in a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nnI2Aa327BAuj7QjI0Om?p=preview)

Comment: Returning true in a foreach loop doesn't prevent extra looping, that is why I recommended using array.prototype.every.  

I already corrected the return value part.

Comment: You right, I changed my code for a classical for() loop.

Comment: so our answers are pretty much identical as for the solution, seems a little redundant.

Comment: It is just another way to get the same result.